# How to invoke "click" event programmatically in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying like that (also at https://gist.github.com/1703994):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.27.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.time.js?1.27.2"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js-libs/jquery-1.7.js"></script>

    <style>
      <!--
      #test {
      width: 400px;
      height: 500px;
      }
      -->
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        var w = 600,
            h = 350;

        var vis = d3.select("#test").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

        var g = vis.selectAll("g")
        .data([ { x:1 , y: 2} ])
        .enter().append("svg:g");

        g.append("svg:path")
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", "10")
        .attr("d", "M 100 350 l 150 -300")

        g.select("path")
        .on("click", function() { console.log("Hello"); });

        // XXX: how to execute click programmaticaly?
      })
    </script>

    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But doesn't work

I think we may use https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#wiki-dispatch_on

But how to do it?

Answer (score 87):

not sure why, but there appears to be a discrepancy with the way jQuery and d3 handle events that causes a jQuery induced click event `$("#some-d3-element").click()` to not dispatch to the d3 element.

a workaround:

```
jQuery.fn.d3Click = function () {
  this.each(function (i, e) {
    var evt = new MouseEvent("click");
    e.dispatchEvent(evt);
  });
};
```

and then call it:

```
$("#some-d3-element").d3Click();
```

Comment: I get this error : Maximum call stack size exceeded. How to solve this ?

Comment: great , but can you help me i want right click now (( can you improve your answer for that thanks.

Answer (score 72):

Simply call the `.on` method as a getter for the registered value (i.e. your handler function), then call the result of that:

```
g.select("path").on("click")();
```

It gets a little more complicated if your handler uses the bound data and/or event fields, or if you've got multiple event listeners bound (e.g "click.thing1" and "click.thing2"). In that case, you're probably best off just firing a fake event using the [standard DOM methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-DocumentEvent):

```
var e = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
e.initUIEvent('click', true, true, /* ... */);
g.select("path").node().dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: For anyone that's using the latter of @natevw's solution, I filled in the remaining values using `window, 1`. The entire call looks like: `e.initUIEvent("click", true, true, window, 1);`

Comment: using the first method, you'll have the wrong "this" - see Andrew Plank's answer for a fix.

Answer (score 35):

With **D3 v4** you will likely want this:

```
d3.select('#some-id').dispatch('click');
```

Ref.: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_dispatch

Comment: this is the best answer as of 09/2020

Comment: If you need to select a single element from a group of elements based on some condition, you can chain the select on to a selectAll like this: `d3.selectAll('.some-class').select(function(d){ if (condition === true) { return this } }).dispatch('click');`.

Answer (score 14):

This works. I'm using pie charts, so I'm selecting all the "selected" pie slices, and for each of them, retrieving the attached "click" callback (that I have attached in another portion of code not included here, using d3's .on() method) and then invoking with the expected parameters in the correct context.

```
d3.selectAll("g.selected").each(function(d, i) {
    var onClickFunc = d3.select(this).on("click");
    onClickFunc.apply(this, [d, i]);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer might be somewhat unrelated - but hopefully useful to someone searching for how to invoke a click event of a SVG element - since jQuery $(mySvgElement).trigger("click") won't work.

This is how you would programmatically trigger/invoke/raise a click event for a SVG element:

```
var ev = document.createEvent("SVGEvents");
ev.initEvent("click",true,true);

var target = $("svg>g>path[fill='#0011cc']").get(0); // get the SVG element here
target.dispatchEvent(ev);  // like $(target).trigger('click') - but working!
```

Answer (score 4):

I came this thread looking for a d3 mousemove event for angular unit testing.

@natevw answer

```
g.select("path").on("click")();
```

helped a lot on mouseover event. But, applying that to mousemove was giving an e.source null error.

The work around was to set the d3 event programmatically.

```
d3.event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
d3.event.initMouseEvent("mousemove");
d3.select(elm[0]).select("rect").on("mousemove")();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can go super manual by getting the mouse event and passing it the arguments that d3 would otherwise provide for you. This gives you a fairly clean way to do it while still using d3 constructs. For a single element use the following:

```
var path = g.select('path');
path.on('click').call(path.node(), path.datum());
```

For multiple elements, you can trigger each one in turn:

```
g.selectAll('path').each(function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).on('click').apply(this, arguments);
});
```

The latter can also be used for a single element if your selector is specific enough, or if you use `.select()` instead of `.selectAll()` to only return the first element.

Answer (score 0):

@handler answer did not work for me entirely. It would click the svg element but additional simulated events would not register. This is what worked for me:

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
eventFire(document.getElementById(element_id), 'click');
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it.

```
g.selectAll("path").on("click", function(d, i){
                                    my_function(d, i);
                                });
```

I've found the the callbacks work with anonymous functions.  So for the code above, any path that is clicked will call `my_function` and pass in the current datum `d` and index `i` of the path that was clicked.

Answer (score -2):

I find next workaround:

```js
d3.selectAll("path").each(function(d, i) {
                    onClickFunc.apply(this, [d, i]);
                });
```

Where `d` is data and `i` is index this data

Comment: this doesn't answer your question really, it just does `d3.selectAll("path").each( onClickFunc )` with more typing. What's onClickFunc?

Comment: This does nothing. Should accept natevw or handler 's answer.

Comment: Missing a vital line of code as the first line of the callback:
    var onClickFunc = d3.select(this).on("click");

Answer (score -5):

Try `g.select("path").trigger("click")`

Comment: doesn't help, d3 not contain `trigger` prop

Comment: sorry, thought it was jQuery, it looks like...
But then I suggest you take this code. It works without any framework, but I only use it under Firefox...
 'var section = document.getElementById("section");
 if (section) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,
    null);
  section.dispatchEvent(evt);
 }'