# nvd3 line chart - rise legend click event programmatically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

How to rise click event on particular legend circle?

I have nvd3 line chart with legend. There are 20 charts displayed. I need always to disable/enable charts by pairs. For example, if user enables 1st chart (by clicking legend circle) I have to manually also enable 11th chart (I thought I can do this by rising click event on 11th circle).

```
chart.legend.dispatch.on('legendClick', function (d, i) {
    // We are here when user clicks on legend item "i"
    // I need enable/disable also item (i+10) and draw charts
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invoke "click" event programmaticaly in d3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063383/how-to-invoke-click-event-programmaticaly-in-d3)