# Understanding "this" reference in D3.js

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I use this code:

```js
d3.selectAll('rect')
.on('mousemove',function(){d3.select(this).attr("fill", "red");})
.on('mouseleave',function(){d3.select(this).attr("fill", "black");})
.on('click', function(){alert(this.tagName);})
;
d3.selectAll('text')
.on('mousemove',function(){d3.select(this.parentNode).select('rect').on('click').apply(this);})
;
```

```css
.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="chart" width="420" height="120">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <rect width="40" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="37" y="9.5" dy=".35em">4</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,20)">
    <rect width="80" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="77" y="9.5" dy=".35em">8</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,40)">
    <rect width="150" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="147" y="9.5" dy=".35em">15</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,60)">
    <rect width="160" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="157" y="9.5" dy=".35em">16</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,80)">
    <rect width="230" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="227" y="9.5" dy=".35em">23</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,100)">
    <rect width="420" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="417" y="9.5" dy=".35em">42</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I expect that when hovering over text element will be triggered event for sibling rect elements and showing message "rect". But the message "text" showed, although code `select('rect')` must be set "this" referenced to rect element. 
Why reference to text element is passed to handler?

Comment: It's because of the way you're calling the click handler. You probably want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063383/how-to-invoke-click-event-programmaticaly-in-d3

Comment: Code "d3.select(this.parentNode).select('rect').on('click')()" also is not works as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` you're passing to `.apply()` refers to the `text` element that the event was fired for, not for the `rect` element you've selected afterwards (selecting an element doesn't change `this`). You need to call the click handler in the new context:

```
d3.selectAll('text')
  .on('mousemove',function(){
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select('rect').each(function() {
      d3.select(this).on("click").apply(this);
    });
  });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8q8f4sv0/).