# d3.js - jasmine test to invoke a click on an svg element

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have a chart directive in my angular application that makes use of the d3.js library.

Part of the directive adds mouse event handlers to some svg elements like so

```
svg.selectAll('g rect')
    .on('click', function(d) {
        scope.clickHandler(d, scope.data);
    })
    .on('mouseover', function () {
        d3.select(this).classed('data-item-hover', true);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function () {
        d3.select(this).classed('data-item-hover', false);
    });
```

I want to cover these handlers in some unit tests, but am struggling with how to actually invoke these events dynamically.

I am attempting this in my test spec

```
describe('scope.clickHandler', function() {
    var rect;
    beforeEach(function(){
        spyOn(scope, 'clickHandler');
        rect = svg.select('g rect')[0][0];
        rect.on('click')();
    });
    it('should call scope.render after a window resize event occurs', function () {
        expect(scope.clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

However this throws an error

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'rect.on('click')'

I came across this SO [How to invoke "click" event programmatically in d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063383/how-to-invoke-click-event-programmatically-in-d3) and the second answer is what has led me to trying this technique.

How can I call a mouse event on the svg elements that I have registered events with in d3.js?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063383/how-to-invoke-click-event-programmatically-in-d3

Comment: That's the exact link I have referenced in the bottom of my question

Comment: My bad :) I can only see a subtle difference: `svg.select('g rect')[0][0]` is a DOM element, while d3 binds methods to the selection array itself, hence the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that `svg.select('g rect')[0][0]` is a DOM element and not a proper D3 selection, that's why you get `undefined` error. From the docs:

> Selections are arrays of elements—literally (maybe not literally...).
>   D3 binds additional methods to the array so that you can apply
>   operators to the selected elements...

You can actually check that since a DOM element implements the `Element` interface:

```
(svg.select('g rect')[0][0] instanceof Element) // true
```

So in order to trigger some event on a certain element, you could do the following:

```
var rect = svg.select('g rect') // first rect element found is assumed
rect.on('click').call(rect.node(), rect.datum()); // as commented in above link
```

You can find a simple working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jarandaf/m1usndrc/).