# How to set the initial selection in a sunburst chart in nvd3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

In nvd3 sunburst plots, the root node is selected/expanded by default. In this example: 
https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/sunburst.html 
that would be the "flare" node.

How can I change the initial selected/expanded node to "query" for example? Or to any other node, programmatically?

Comment: tumbleweed badge, yay!

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @fara natevw's solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063383/how-to-invoke-click-event-programmatically-in-d3 worked for me